# Couldn't access LinkedIn's My Apps link in developer

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to edit something in my app on LinkedIn, but I keep getting nothing when I go to the My Apps page, even if I go to the app link itself. All the other links are working except for this. I thought it's just a browser issue but I also used Safari and I'm getting the same result.

I looked at the console and one of the errors I saw is `Uncaught Error: No template found in the cache with ID 'templates/partials/body_top' for embed with ID 'templates/partials/body_top'`

I know I can't fix this (duh) but anyone else experiencing this?